# Keycloak Javascript Mapper not working as expected

Tags: javascript, keycloak

I did the following script for mapping an attribute called DocumentType for a SAML response, I have the document type and also document number of the person inside this attribute called LDAP_ID so I need to separate them, I tried like so:

```
DocumentType=(user.LDAP_ID).substring(0,2);
```

But when I check the response the value of attribute DocumentType is empty, but my `user.LDAP_ID` does contain a value like for example cc23143212, what am I doing wrong?

I also tried to do

```
DocumentType = String(user.LDAP_ID); // but this is returning undefined
```

what am I missing?

If I set `DocumentType = user.LDAP_ID;` then in the response, this attribute DocumentType contains value cc23143212

**UPDATE:**

I have another user attribute called username, which also contains the document number and documenttype of the user together like cc23143212, I tried using this attribute and it works, like so:

```
DocumentType = (user.username).substring(0,2); // returns cc as expected
```

so I think that the problem is something with the type of variable user.LDAP_ID is not an string or idk really why it does not work with attribute LDAP_ID, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If LDAP_ID is stored in an attribute LDAP_ID, you can try

```
String(user.getAttribute("LDAP_ID")).substring(0,2)
```

Comment: I tried with this way but it is giving me the same behaviour :(

Comment: And can you see the LDAP_ID on the Attributes Tab?
Which Version are you using? In newer versions (for example kc 16) LDAP_ID is a reserved attribute, so possily you can not create it in the identity-provider mapper. Are there any errors in the log?

Comment: It is in the attributes tab of the users, I am using version 16.1.1, I can access the attribute but if I do a substring to it or anything that envolves making a process or calculation with it, it becomes undefined/blank, it looks like it is a READ ONLY attribute but very strict one... Because even if I create another variable and assign it the value of LDAP_ID, if I try to play with the new variable it is the same result

Comment: I updated my suggestion

Comment: After your update, it is is giving me a different result, it is letting me manipulate the value but it is showing me the attribute like so: [cc1000089266], so when I do substring (0, 2) the result is "[c" any idea why it is adding the "[]" at begining and end of the variable? I can work now with the attribute but wonder if that can be prevented

Comment: That is because the attributes are returned from keycloak as array

Comment: So is this the best way to do it mate? or is it a way I can get only cc1000089266 without the []? It is so bad that keycloak does not allow to just do user.getAttribute("LDAP_ID").substring(0,2);

Comment: The problem is, that you are operating somewhere between java and javascript.
The getAttribute() Call returns a java-array and if you apply Javascript String() to it, you get a js string. You can do something like this:


if (user.getAttribute("LDAP_ID") && user.getAttribute("LDAP_ID").length > 0) {
  var fuddel =  String(user.getAttribute("LDAP_ID")[0]).substring(0,2);
  token.setOtherClaims("Fuddel", fuddel);
}

or if you prefer operating ins javasript:
var userId = user.getAttribute("LDAP_ID");
if (userId && userId.toString().startsWith("[") && userId.length > 0) {
}